# The Datalab package keeps complaining about missing dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, importerror

In order to solve this problem, I newly created the conda environment and installed the related packages through pip install cleanlab[datalab], but the program still gave an error. I tried for several days and did not solve the problem.code：

```
import sys
print(f"Python executable: {sys.executable}")

from cleanlab import Datalab

lab = Datalab({"X": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "y": ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a"]})

print(lab)
```

Output：

```
 Python executable: D:\Anaconda3\envs\new_cleanlab_env\python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\papers\code\scr\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    lab = Datalab({"X": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "y": ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a"]})
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\new_cleanlab_env\lib\site-packages\cleanlab\__init__.py", line 29, in __call__
    raise ImportError(message)
ImportError: Datalab is not available due to missing dependencies. To install Datalab, run `pip install 'cleanlab[datalab]'`. (raised when trying to call with args: ({'X': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']},), kwargs: {})

进程已结束,退出代码1
```

I tried to recreate the environment or install the dependencies again and again, but it still gave me the same error. May I ask where the problem may be?